# Causality of z-transform $a^nu[n+1]$

Tags: z-transform, poles-zeros

To preface, this is not a homework related question but purely for self-study purposes.

I'm try to do the analyse of z-transform of $a^nu[n+1]$. It is clearly a non-causal signal, I try to explain it by using the definition.

Based on the causality of z-transform definition: If x(n) is a infinite duration causal sequence, ROC is exterior of the circle with radius a. i.e. $|z| > |a|$.

I am not sure if my explanation is correct: 
$$\mathcal{Z}\big\{a^nu[n+1]\big\} = a^{-1}z+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (a/z)^{n}$$

The ROC of this function in z-plane is $|z| > |a|$ except at $z = ∞$.

It does not obey the causality definition because the boundary exists ( $|a|<|z|< ∞ $), i.e. the ROC pattern is a ring, it is a non-causal signal.

Am I correct? I am kinda confused with the causality definition.

Comment: **Signals** just are.  **Systems** can be non-causal.  That signal description just says that it starts before $n = 0$ and remains non-zero to $n = +\infty$.  Because, in signal processing convention, $n = 0$ means "now" and not the moment of the big bang, it's perfectly acceptable (if mathematically awkward) to have a signal that's nonzero for $n < 0$.  Generally, if it happens (and it's not an impulse response, which *does* indicate a non-causal *system*), then it's most convenient to just change your time index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. If the region of convergence of a right-sided signal (like the one you have) does **not** include infinity, then the signal is not causal.

Comment: How can a **signal** be noncausal?  Signals just *are*, whenever they are.  They can be non-zero at any arbitrary spot in time.  *Systems* can be noncausal, by predicting the future -- but signals are handed to us by the universe, not always on a platter.

Comment: Technically, you are absolutely right. Signals just *are* and systems can be characterized as causal or not. However, it is very common to call signals as causal if $$x(t) = 0, t < 0$$ and anti-causal if $$x(t) = 0, t> 0$$ The term is obviously borrowed from systems and their impulse response.

Comment: Hmm.  I wonder when that came into common use?  My intuition says "blech".

Comment: At least 4 years ago :) : https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27143/what-is-causal-signal